# How I can load objects (.obj or .gltf) dynamically for using in AR app for Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, augmented-reality, android-augmented-reality

I have online store of home decor things. And I want to create an Android app with supporting AR. For example, user will select chair, and if he wants, he can see this chair in AR (in room).

Comment: what exactly do you want to achieve

Comment: https://www.raywenderlich.com/408-getting-started-with-arcore-with-kotlin check this tutorial

Comment: I want all the objects to load dynamically through the api, because the content will constantly change. But I do not know how to store them on the server. In what format to store? only .gltf or .mlt too? and how to get them?